# send content from node.js to jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

How can I send back the content of document the a existing view ('index.jade') without reloading the entire page but just the content of a div?

this is a search and its going to update on every keydown with will lead to a lot of site updates in other case,

I'm thankful for all help!

node

```
function pagelist(items) {
  var db = db_login;
  console.log(items)
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item)
    db.collection('insights').findById(item._id , function(error, document) {
    console.log(document)
    if (error || !document) {
        res.render('error', {});
        } else {
        console.log(document.insightheader)

        //SEND BACK CONTENT

        }})

 });
}
```

Comment: You mean you want the page to do an AJAX request to a handler on the backend that will respond with back with data? Dunno if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: yes that what i want

Comment: you can do something like this, [Issue with Rendering templates with jade](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26437513/3423104)

Comment: You can't send "back". HTTP doesn't work that way. (Sockets do that, if you wanna look into it.) But for HTTP you have to make a new request and handle it from server each time you want to send new content. AJAX lets you make new requests from client-side javascript (instead of reloading the page). You would probably wanna separate your views (what you render) and your data exchange logic so both can work independently of one another (i.e. you can exchange data from server from the same view).

Comment: On the backend, did you try using res.send()? I use it to send only data. Just create a handler that doesn't have a res.render(), but a res.send().